# Django Python - Displaying data from models.py to html page ... error too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django

I am using Django as a webframework for a project. I am having trouble displaying data that was saved into models.py to my html page. For a little background we are doing sentiment analysis with Python's textblob package. The analysis is performed in analysis.py and is called in our views.py by using the call_command(analysis) that Django provides.

Below is what we have:

analysis.py

```
pt_terrible = SentimentPercentage(pt_terrible = (len(terrible_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
pt_terrible.save()
```

models.py

```
class SentimentPercentage(models.Model):
    pt_terrible = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_bad = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_neutral = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_good = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_excellent = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def results(request):
    sentiment = call_command('analysis')
    terrible_sentiment = SentimentPercentage.objects.get('**pt_terrible')
    context = {'sentiment': sentiment, 'terrible_sentiment': terrible_sentiment}
    return render(request, 'sawa/results.html', context)
```

results.html

```
<section>
            <form>
                <fieldset>

                    <!-- RESULTS WILL BE POSTED HERE -->

                    <p>{{terrible_sentiment.pt_terrible}}</p>

                    <p>RESULTS WILL BE POSTED HERE</p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </section>
```

We are receiving the error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"... Below is the Traceback:

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/sawa/results/

Django Version: 1.9.5
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['sawa.apps.SawaConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response 149.response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response 147.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\...\Documents\Spring Semester 2016\ISA 406\Project\Django Project\isa406\sawa\views.py" in results 17.terrible_sentiment = SentimentPercentage.objects.get('**pt_terrible')

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method 122.return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get 378.clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter 790.return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude 808.clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q 1243.clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
```

We have tried a bunch of things with the views.py to get it working with no luck. If you have any suggestions, we would very much appreciate it.

Comment: You need to show us the full trackback.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the traceback which would enable us to easily diagnose the problem, but this line looks suspicious:

```
 terrible_sentiment = SentimentPercentage.objects.get('**pt_terrible')
```

The argument should not be in quotes.

Comment: Trace back has been added.

Comment: Well, looks like I guessed right, since the same line is highlighted in the traceback. Did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes, just tried removing the quotes. I now receive the error "name 'pt_terrible' is not defined"

Comment: I was playing with my code yesterday and managed to get by the problem. However now I have a new problem with displaying the results. I will post a new question to address it.